# Is a CANopen Object Dictionary dynamically retrievable?

Tags: canopen

I have a device (Electric motor controller) that has some decent documentation about its CANOpen implementation. However, there are some entries that are missing or where I think the documentation is wrong.

Is there an SDO or other way to have a CANopen-compliant device spit out its object dictionary including all information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way of doing this by specification. If you don't have the .EDS file you are limited to polling the configuration entries with normal SDO-inquiries.